# Install an older version of postfix on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: postfix, ubuntu-14.10

I have inherited a set of Ubuntu boxes (different versions) that process emails and replies using postfix and other tools.

Two Ubuntu 14.10 boxes have started giving out incorrect results and after investigating a little closer I noticed that the version of postfix has changed on those two machines and I am not able to revert back to the old version.

The version that should be installed is 2.11.0 but these were updated to 2.11.1.

I am not able to find the previous version in the apt repositories. Is there any way I can install 2.11.0 using apt or do I need to look for the source and install from scratch?

Comment: You're looking at it backwards.  If there's an issue, address the issue directly.  Minor version changes like that should not impact behavior unless there was a specific bug you relied on which would be quite surprising.

Comment: sudo apt-get install postfix=2.11.0-1 ?

Comment: I have tried postfix=2.11.0-1 but did not work, I have however taken Julies' advice and found that the issue is elsewhere. Thank you both for the comments.

Comment: Why do you need an *outdated* version of postfix?